# Implementing dynamic dropdown menu in Polymer2.0. Works in Polymer1.0 but not in Polymer2.0

Tags: polymer-1.0, shadow-dom, polymer-2.x, polymer-starter-kit

I've done the following using `Polymer1`. Doing the same in `Polymer2.0` does not trigger the automatic dropdown menu of the `button`. 
Please could someone tell me what to do. It seems to have to do with `Shadow DOM`.

In `Polymer1`, the `index.html` has `dom ='shadow'`, and a `<content>` tag instead of `<slot>`, and it gets to the `dReadyDynamicRightMenuReady` and triggers the dropdown. 
But in `Polymer2.0` it also gets to this function, and does not trigger the dropdown.

```
<!-- this is in my-spxl Polymer2.0 -->
<paper-menu-button class="userMenuPositionClass">
<paper-icon-button icon="menu" class="dropdown-trigger"></paper-icon-button>
<paper-dropdown-menu class="dropdown-content">
    <iron-selector selected="[[choice]]" attr-for-selected="mychoice" role="navigation">
       <template id="" is="dom-repeat" items="[[dReadyDynamicRightMenuReady]]" as="menuOption">
           <paper-item>... </paper-item>
       </template>
    </iron-selector>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
</paper-menu-button>
```

`<paper-button class="">
<img on-tap="openRightMenuFromPhoto" src="[[user.photoURL]]">
</paper-button>`

Script:
     `openRightMenuFromPhoto() {
        var usersMenuButton = this.$.userMenuIconId; 
        usersMenuButton.click(function(event) {
        dReadyDynamicRightMenuReady = [
            { "myChoice": "spx21", "myHref": "/spx21", "myOptionValue": "chats" }
        ];
        return dReadyDynamicRightMenuReady;
       })
      }`

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, some tags didn't print in the above. Errata: In Polymer1, the index.html has dom ='shadow', and a content tag instead of slot (which is for Polymer2.0),...

Comment: Can you provide the script part as well?

Comment: Thanks for the edit Ofisora. Script provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few mistakes in your code:

1. Handle and firing events:

   Click listeners is inside a function. That will never be called. Put event listeners on `ready()` or `connectedCallback`. For more information about how to do that [click here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/events#imperative-listeners).
2. Setting property value:

   Setting properties value inside function and returning it won't set it. Use 
   `this.property = value` and notify the changes. OR, if it is an array/object use [polymer array mutation methods](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/model-data#array-mutation).
3. Read the [documentation](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-menu-button) of `paper-menu-button`:

   Instead of `class='dropdown-trigger'` use `slot` as in documentation.

Also, try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you very much Ofisora! Other content overlaps the menu, but this works. Will make minimal etc. Thanks!